# \sectionref and \subsectionref

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm using a custom counter which I increment every now and then :

```
\newcounter{MyCounter}[subsection]
\newcommand{\stepTheCounter}{%
    % do stuff, whatever
    \refstepcounter{MyCounter}
}
```

Then, if I use a `\label{someLabel}` somewhere, I would like to be able to have a custom command `\theReference{someLabel}`, so that if I have a line like `Lorem ipsum dolor \theReference{someLabel} sit amet`, it shows something like

> Lorem ipsum dolor `X`.`Y`.`Z` (page `W`) sit amet

where `X` is the section number, `Y` is the subsection number, `Z` is the value gotten from `\ref{someLabel}`, and `W` is the value gotten from `\pageref{someLabel}`.

So the thing is : there *is* a `\pageref` command, but (supposedly ?) no `\etionref` nor `\subsectionref` commands. But I feel like it should be *normal* to be able to achieve this easily...

None of the threads opened on the TeXExchange helped me... Thanks for the kind replies !

Comment: the usual  format is to define \theMyCounter as `\thesubsection.\arabic{MyCounter}` then `\ref` will give the full section.subsection.Mycounter value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose two ways depending on what you want `\theMyCounter` to do.

## First way

If you want `\theMyCounter` to print the plain counter number, you can use:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{MyCounter}
\labelformat{MyCounter}{\thesubsection.#1}

\newcommand{\stepTheCounter}{%
 % do stuff, whatever
 \refstepcounter{MyCounter}%
}
\newcommand*{\myRef}[1]{\ref{#1} (page~\pageref{#1})}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}

Foo bar.\stepTheCounter\label{first}
\verb|\theMyCounter| yields \theMyCounter.
The second use of \verb|\stepTheCounter| is \myRef{second}.
\newpage

\section{Second section}
\subsection{A subsection}

Bla. \stepTheCounter\label{second}
\verb|\theMyCounter| yields \theMyCounter.
The first use of \verb|\stepTheCounter| is \myRef{first}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

...

[image]

## Second way

If you prefer `\theMyCounter` to print something like 2.1.2 (assuming the `\stepTheCounter` call preceding the `\label` was in section 2, subsection 1), then simply replace the line:

```latex
\labelformat{MyCounter}{\thesubsection.#1}
```

with:

```latex
\renewcommand{\theMyCounter}{\thesubsection.\arabic{MyCounter}}
```

and the output will be as follows.

[image]

...

[image]

Of course, you'll probably want to call these inside a subsection (if you use `\stepTheCounter` inside a section but not inside a subsection, the `subsection` counter will be zero).

Comment: That's amazing, exactly what I needed, thank you so much !

Comment: Glad to help. :-)